# Is there a way to install pytest on wingide?

Tags: python, pytest, wing-ide

I know this might seem like a dumb question but is there a way to install pytest on wingide as I am in need.

I have tried looking for tutorials and getting help but I can't seem to figure out.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to install it using pip:

```
pip install pytest
```

or:

```
python -m pip install pytest
```

You do have to make sure you're using the right pip or python, to match the one that you are using in Wing.  If you have Wing Pro you can also use the Packages tool in the Tools menu to install pytest.  Use Install New Packages from the tool's Options menu.

Note that if you installed pytest while Wing is running, you'll have to restart your debug process or Python Shell (from its Options menu) before you can import purest.

Once you've installed Pytest, you should be able to run and debug pytest-based unit tests from Wing Pro's Testing tool.  You  may need to set the testing framework to Pytest using the Configure Testing option in the Testing menu.  See https://wingware.com/doc/testing for details.

Comment: I mean pytest in my question not purest

Comment: I've edited the answer accordingly. :-)